# why pyinstaller kepp throwing codesign failure while my script has been signied?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, codesign

im on macbook old version El Capitan 10.11.6 and my python script is 147bytes just for auto shutdown program but when i try to boundle it pyinstaller filename.py it done almost everything and end up with (codesign failure). do someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in your terminal, type: `sudo codesign -f -s` followed by your script name `test.py` Make sure you are in your script file directory by using cd path to your file folder.
After that, you can run `pyinstaller test.py` However, I am using macOS Monterey Version 12.6 and am not sure if it will work on your current version. In fact, I don't even know how that command makes it work, but it works for me. If your app is a windowed app, such as the Tkinter app, your system may prevent it from opening; in that case, use the following command to disable the security system `sudo spctl --master-disable` . then you will see a new option available in your macOS Settings under Security; down there it says Allow app from: App Store, App Store and identified developer; and at last, you will see a new option "Anywhere" which wasn't there before; check that, and your app will work perfectly. hope helped